# Segmentation fault: 11 related to extending `Error` protocol with an enum

Tags: xcode, swift3, xcode8

After upgrading from Xcode 8 beta 3 to Xcode 8 beta 4 (8S188o) and doing the usual renaming migrations, I was still seeing 9 or more Build errors labeled helpfully as `Segmentation Fault: 11`.

I noticed these all relate to our application's `Error` extending enum. I built an isolated test project, and now I can re-create this problem with only this code (so you can you--drop this into any project and watch the fireworks):

```
enum AppError: Error {
  case one
  case two
}

protocol ErrorReceiver {
  func thingError(with: AppError)
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, ErrorReceiver {
  func thingError(with error: AppError) {
    print(error)
  }
}
```

The code above crashes the build, but if I make the tiny change below, the build works:

```
enum AppError { // Changed: don't conform to `Error`
```

Of course this isn't acceptable for our app, as we want to throw and catch Error objects of types we designate.

It also fixes it if I use a struct or class:

```
struct AppError: Error { // Changed: use a struct
```

But we switch on the error type everywhere and use associated values, so this seems like a huge refactor. It's also a less-clear representation of what we're trying to model I think. If that's what I have to do to build though, I may have to.

I've tried flipping the build switches off and on again, doing clean builds, exiting and re-entering  xcode, and even upgraded to beta 5; but to no avail.

- Is there something wrong with my pattern of extending the base `Error` class with an enum in the latest swift 3 build? (worked great until now)

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What is on line `161` in the file `MenuDisplayer.swift`?

Comment: Seems like a bug in Xcode ; it maybe be worth trying 7.3.1 if it all possible to see if the issue persists.

Comment: In that case I would probably try changing your protocol to use conforming types with instance methods that call the functions within the class — a basic example being like this: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/2365a105f7a8ce10d72e40cff7b07015

Comment: Submitted to apple radar as 27787072

Comment: Okay, I think I see what to do. See my answer below. (Very nice bug, by the way. I would suggest submitting to bugs.swift.org too. Let me know if you need me to do that for you.)

Comment: reported also as https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-2312, Thanks Matt

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be that Swift doesn't like your passing the error enum around (as the type of a function parameter).

You can work around this for now by making AppError a struct. With some thought, this can be done without serious loss of generality.

Comment: Bummer. We have a large amount of application code that `switch`es on the error it's been given. See any way around this? Perhaps I put an enum inside the error struct. Just so much refactoring. Some of the cases have associated values, like `.notFound(id: Int)` Can I implement a `switchable` conformance for a `struct` type?

Answer (score 1):

1. This is definitely a [bug](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-2312).
2. This bug happens as part of exposing the method to Objective-C, so you can work around this by adding `@nonobjc` (Thanks @JordanRose!):

eg:

```
enum AppError: Error {
  case one
  case two
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, ErrorReceiver {
  @nonobjc
  func thingError(with error: AppError) {
    print(error)
  }
}
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for reporting back. I _told_ you submitting to swiftbugs would be a good idea! [rant] Why haven't lots of people upvoted your question? You posed this issue _brilliantly_! If only everyone did so much preparatory work before asking a question on Stack Overflow, this would be a bright beautiful world!! [rant off] Okay, I'm calming down now...

Comment: Thanks for suggesting that route Matt. I have been so discouraged by Apple bug reporting (no transparency, marked as duplicate) that I almost didn't. Swift bug reporting is great though.

Comment: :) I knew that's what you'd discover!